# How to encapsulate loader service logic using BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a loader service from Angular University course:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

  showLoaderUntilCompleted<T>(obs$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return of(null).pipe(
      tap(() => this.on()),
      concatMap(() => obs$),
      finalize(() => this.off())
    );
  }

  on() {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
  }

  off() {
    this.loadingSubject.next(false);
  }
}
```

And it's usage in a component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [LoadingService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  loading$: Observable<boolean>;
  constructor(private loader: LoadingService) {
    this.loading$ = loader.loading$;
  }
  submit() {
    this.loader.showLoaderUntilCompleted(timer(1000)).subscribe();
  }

  submit2() {
    this.loader.showLoaderUntilCompleted(timer(1000)).subscribe();
  }
}
```

And the template:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  {{ loading$ | async }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form (ngSubmit)="submit2()">
  {{ loading$ | async }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It works perfectly in a case when component has only one form, can someone suggest how can I reuse it with multiple forms on the page?
The goal is to have different loader states for each form.

Link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjorfp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered the question yourself. *"The goal is to have different loader states for each form"* - so each form needs it's own loader.

You could create two different instances of the service for two separate unrelated loaders.

**Controller**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [LoadingService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private loader1: LoadingService;
  private loader2: LoadingService;

  loading1$: Observable<boolean>;
  loading2$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.loader1 = new LoadingService();
    this.loader2 = new LoadingService();

    this.loading1$ = this.loader1.loading$;
    this.loading2$ = this.loader2.loading$;
  }

  submit() {
    this.loader1.showLoaderUntilCompleted(timer(1000)).subscribe();
  }

  submit2() {
    this.loader2.showLoaderUntilCompleted(timer(1000)).subscribe();
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    {{ loading1$ | async }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form (ngSubmit)="submit2()">
    {{ loading2$ | async }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mxw1co?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: is it legal to inject a service like this? Will I have any other limitations using ```new LoadingService();``` ?

Comment: Injecting the service takes advantage of Typescript's [Parameter Properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties). It _approximately_ gets expanded to the same form as shown here. You could also see here in this [Playground](https://cutt.ly/fzrmWfJ). If you're still doubtful you could also do `constructor(private loader1: LoadingService, private loader2: LoadingService)` and remove the manual definitions and assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This aslo can be done with injection token [injection token doc](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken)

```
const FORM1_LOADER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('form1-loader-token');
const FORM2_LOADER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('form2-loader-token');

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: FORM1_LOADER_TOKEN,
            useClass: LoadingService
        },
        {
            provide: FORM2_LOADER_TOKEN,
            useClass: LoadingService
        }
    ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    loading1$: Observable<boolean>;
    loading2$: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(
        @Inject(FORM1_LOADER_TOKEN) private loader1: LoadingService,
        @Inject(FORM2_LOADER_TOKEN) private loader2: LoadingService
    ) {
        this.loading1$ = this.loader1.loading$;
        this.loading2$ = this.loader2.loading$;
    }

    submit() {
        this.loader1.showLoaderUntilCompleted(timer(1000)).subscribe();
    }

    submit2() {
        this.loader2.showLoaderUntilCompleted(timer(1000)).subscribe();
    }
}
```